# This Repository does not have a release file error on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, aptitude

So a few weeks back I tried to install the GitHub CLI on my Ubuntu machine via shell, and now every time I try to update I get the following error:

```
E: The repository 'https://cli.github.com/packages kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm unable to open any GUI since I am using this machine strictly from a shell. It's currently on Ubuntu 22.10, can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked at `apt-secure` as suggested by the error message? It tells you how to get past the error and points you to editing `sources.list` to make changes to this specific repository.

Comment: how could I do that? Not really familiar with the command.

Comment: I can't give you any more information than the man pages provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your APT source is wrong, it should contain `stable`, not `kinetic`.
Remove the offending source in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or if it's defined in its own file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, delete it.

Use `grep` to find it:

```
grep -r kinetic /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

That's it.

If you still want to (re)install GitHub CLI, follow the [Debian, Ubuntu Linux, Raspberry Pi OS (apt) installation steps](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md#debian-ubuntu-linux-raspberry-pi-os-apt):

```
type -p curl >/dev/null || sudo apt install curl -y
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& sudo chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null \
&& sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install gh -y
```

Too much to type? I added the steps to a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ejJNbaE8) to make it easier for you to download and execute the snippet. Make sure to check its content before you run it!

```
curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/ejJNbaE8 | tr -d '\r' | sh
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I just solved it bu doing `sudo rm [filename]` from the sources list and now apt update works again.